# Variable is undefined error (even if console.log shows variable)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My function looks like that

```
var mail_ntfy=$("#nav_mail"), question_ntfy=$("#nav_question"), users_ntfy=$("#nav_users");
function CheckAll(){
    var data=checkFor("m,q,u");
    if(mail_ntfy.attr("data-number")!=data.m_count && data.m_count!=0)
        mail_ntfy.attr("data-number", data.m_count);
    if(question_ntfy.attr("data-number")!=data.q_count && data.q_count!=0)
        question_ntfy.attr("data-number", data.q_count);
    if(users_ntfy.attr("data-number")!=data.u_count && data.u_count!=0)
        users_ntfy.attr("data-number", data.u-count);
    showNotes(data.msg);
    chngTitle(data.msg);    
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(CheckAll(), 10000);
})

function checkFor(param){    
    $.ajax({
        url: "core/notifications.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            chk:param
        },
        success: function (data) { 
            if(data.status!="error")  {
                console.log(data);
                return data;                
            }

        }
    });
}
```

I got 2 questions:

1) I see that, `checkFor` function returns result (console.log shows result) but still getting data is undefined error message on line `if(mail_ntfy.attr("data-number")!=data.m_count && data.m_count!=0)`. What am I missing?

2) I want to execute, `CheckAll` in every 10 seconds. But it doesn't start more than 1 time. why setinterval doesn't work properly?

Answer (score 1):

You can't return data from `success` callback. Instead you can call `CheckAll` from success callback like this

```
success: function (data) { 
            if(data.status!="error")  {
                console.log(data);
                //return data;                
                CheckAll(data);
            }

        }
```

To run `checkFor` instead every 10 seconds you can set the timer from within success callback too. That will call the `checkFor` 10 seconds after every successful ajax request. Using `setInterval` can end up with multiple simultaneous ajax calls.

```
success: function (data) { 
                if(data.status!="error")  {
                    console.log(data);
                    //return data;                
                    CheckAll(data);
                    setTimeout(checkFor,10000);
                }

            }
```

And your updated `checkAll` would be like

```
function CheckAll(data){

    if(mail_ntfy.attr("data-number")!=data.m_count && data.m_count!=0)
        mail_ntfy.attr("data-number", data.m_count);
    if(question_ntfy.attr("data-number")!=data.q_count && data.q_count!=0)
        question_ntfy.attr("data-number", data.q_count);
    if(users_ntfy.attr("data-number")!=data.u_count && data.u_count!=0)
        users_ntfy.attr("data-number", data.u-count);
    showNotes(data.msg);
    chngTitle(data.msg);    
}
```

Comment: @epic_syntax: You cant. It's aynchronous.

Comment: @epic_syntax: you don't return. But you can do things in CPS style, just like the AJAX request itself is. Have your function receive another function to call when its done and call that function from inside the AJAX callback, passing the "return value" as an argument to it.

Answer (score 1):

`checkFor()` does *not* return any result. The `console.log()` statement is in the anonymous function attached to the `success` handler of your AJAX request; its return does *not* return from the `checkFor()` function.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `checkFor` to return the `data` the AJAX call has to be synchronous. This is, however, bad Javascript practice (for example, it will hang the execution of scripts on the page until the request is complete). Unfortunately this whole design is flawed, but you could use this code if you REALLY have to:

```
function checkFor(param){    
  var result;
  $.ajax({
    url: "core/notifications.php",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        chk:param
    },
    success: function (data) { 
        if(data.status!="error")  {
            console.log(data);
            result = data;                
        }

    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling Ajax asynchronously therefore the system wont wait for ajax to end in order to continue proccessing. You'll have to add

```
async:false,
```

To your ajax call, like this:

```
function checkFor(param){    
    $.ajax({
        url: "core/notifications.php",
        type: "POST",
        async:false,
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            chk:param
        },
        success: function (data) { 
            if(data.status!="error")  {
                console.log(data);
               var ret=data;                
            }

        }
    });
return ret;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: this is wrong, it will not return the `data` to the caller of `checkFor`